# How to solve Creating default object from empty value?

Tags: php, php-5.3

I found something about this error but I think this is little bit different. I defined a public variable.

```
Class Controller{    
    public $model;
```

And I'm trying add extra word(`model`) between `$model_name` and `$this`.

```
public function call_model($model_name){
$this->model->$model_name = new $model_class;
```

What is the solution?

EDIT:

```
Warning: Creating default object from empty value in C:\xampp\htdocs\alisveris\project_library\Controller.php on line 16
```

Comment: What? If you want to have a property `$model` that has properties itself, it needs to be a object itself

Comment: Then need i hide the errors? or delete the 'model'?

Comment: Your problem is not clear. Please provide more details.

Comment: @chanchal118 I have added warning..

Comment: what does the $model_class variable contains? It seems to me that it is empty, and therefore you are getting that error.

Answer (score 1):

You can create static factory method to create different models like this:

```
abstract class Model {
 static function CallModel($name) {
  switch ( $name ) {
   case 'Naomi': return new NaomiCampbell();
   case 'Anja': return new AnjaRubik();
   default: return new $name;
  }
 }
}

class NaomiCampell extends Model {}
class AnjaRubik extends Model {}
```

Then use:

```
$MyModel = Model::CallModel($name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by assigning $model variable to $this

```
 class Db
  {
         public function great()
         {
             echo 'great';
         }
  }


 class Controller{

     public $model;

     public function __construct()
     {
         $this->model = $this;

         $model_name = 'Db';
         $this->model->$model_name = new $model_name;

     }
 }

 $cc = new Controller();

 echo $cc->model->Db->great();
```

Output

```
great
```